# After logging in to Facebook via SDK, it just stays in the browser window

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK in iOS. I can login but it doesn't return from the browser window.

This is what it looks like

- [Login button is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/619CM.png)
- I then come to stage which says that I have already logged in to my app
- [Browser just stays there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nPEw.png)

I have added the `Info.plist` stuff, both the standard stuff found here (facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#xcode) under "Configure Xcode project", and iOS 9 things found here (facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) under "Whitelist Facebook Servers for Network Requests". Also the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` stuff.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For someone needing it, i have the same error, fixed it by adding this to

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    //Optionally add to ensure your credentials are valid:
    FBSDKLoginManager.renewSystemCredentials { (result:ACAccountCredentialRenewResult, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        //
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    //Even though the Facebook SDK can make this determinitaion on its own,
    //let's make sure that the facebook SDK only sees urls intended for it,
    //facebook has enough info already!
    let isFacebookURL = url.scheme.hasPrefix("fb\(FBSDKSettings.appID())") && url.host == "authorize"
    if isFacebookURL {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
    return false
}
```